# Prove that there are infinitely many primes p, such that the congruence $x^7$ + $3x^5 + 1 \equiv 0 \mod p$ has a solution

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How would you go about solving this? What kind of proof should i use? Any help will be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You could use this kind of proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2899219/prove-that-there-are-infinitely-many-primes-p-such-that-x10-x-1-equiv), by contradiction.

Comment: Instead, you may also use something called Chebotarev density theorem (which proves a stronger result, that this kind of prime numbers have positive density).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $1+3+1=5$, there is at least one such prime. So, suppose that there are only a finite number of such primes and let $P$ be their product.

Let $q$ be any prime dividing $P^7+3P^5+1$. Then $q$ is not a factor of $P$, a contradiction.